# Matlab - Removing extracting certain charecters/numbers from char cells in a cell array

Tags: matlab, char, extract

I have a Matlab cell array, A  <118080 x 1 cell> that look something like this:

```
"Point 1"
"Point 2"
"Point 3"
...
"Point 1230"
```

The cells are char cells of between 1x9 and 1x12 dimensions.

I need to seperate the numbers from these fields to give a 118080 x 1 matrix like:

```
1
2
3
...
1230
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best

Sam (A Matlab Newbie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cellfun(@(x)(x(7:end)), A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

or if you want them as numbers then

```
cellfun(@(x)(str2num(x(7:end))), A)
```

Comment: Hi Dan! Thanks for the help, I have a small follow up. I ideally do need them as numbers but when I use your suggested formula I get the message: Error using cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false. I tried using the original formula instead as suggested and got a list like 1",2",3",4" ... 1230" I don't suppose you have any thoughts?

Comment: @IdleSam sure, just add  `,'UniformOutput', false)` to the end of the second method

Comment: Nevermind, I typed before I thought. I just amended your orignal code for numbers to  `cellfun(@(x)(str2num(x(7:end-1))),A)` and this gave me exactly what I needed. Many thanks Dan!

Answer (score 2):

A solution without `cellfun` that uses `regexp` (only the numbers are kept here)

```
A = {'Point 1'
     'Point 222'
     'Point 33333'}

B = regexp(A, '\d+', 'match');  %produce a cell array of numbers in string format
```

If you want to convert the cells into a matrix

```
B = str2double([B{:}])';        %convert to numbers
```